# How to save multiple objects at once to Django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to get form data using a `POST` request and save the form data to  my database which was created using a django model, which is `InfoModel`. I'm getting the data from the `POST` request, but I don't know how to save all of it at once so that it all saves to the same row in the db. The way I'm doing it now, each object from the form saves to a different row of the database which is obviously not useful at all. I expect the answer is simple, but I haven't seen this in the docs.

views.py:

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # if POST request, validate the data
        form = InfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # if the form is valid, collect the data, submit to db, and thank the user
            valid = True
            form_data = request.POST
            f = InfoModel(fname=form_data['fname'])
            f.save()
            l = InfoModel(lname=form_data['lname'])
            l.save()
            e = InfoModel(email=form_data['email'])
            e.save()
            p = InfoModel(phone=form_data['phone'])
            p.save()
            return render(request, 'form_db/home.html', {'form': form, 'valid': valid})
        else:
            # if the form is invalid, populate the form with the entered data and show error message
            valid = False
            form = InfoForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, 'form_db/home.html', {'form': form, 'valid': valid})
    else:
        # if GET request, return blank form as normal
        form = InfoForm()
        return render(request, 'form_db/home.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply, give all fields' names of your `InfoModel` at once in the following way:

```
if form.is_valid():
    valid=True
    fName=form.cleaned_data['fname']
    lname=form.cleaned_data['lname']
    email=form.cleaned_data['email']
    phone=form.cleaned_data['phone']
 
    instance=InfoModel(fname=fName,lname=lname,email=email,phone=phone)
    instance.save()
    return render(request,"form_db/home.html",{'form': form,'valid':valid})
```

> `Note:` Models in django doesn't require model to be the suffix, so it will be better if you only give model name `Info` rather than `InfoModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `f = InfoModel()` you are instantiating a new instance, and then saving it using `f.save()`, which is why you are getting so many rows.  All this is unnecessary since a form has it's own [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method, which will save all the fields at once into ONE row.

The best way to handle forms is to use the classic [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method where if the form data comes in as Post, then you process it and redirect, usually back to the same view, but it can be another view as well.  If it is a Get, then you render the blank form.

```py
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = InfoForm(request.POST or None)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
     
        return render(request, 'form_db/home.html', {'form':form})
```

Note the `form = InfoForm(request.POST or None)`, which is handy since it will create a blank form with the `None` if it is not a Post request, but if it is will fill the form with the data `request.POST` if it's a Post request.